# No output tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Any ideas on why this doesnt print hey in terminal? Im trying to make a calculator, but first I have to know wether the person know the in game currency (credits) or the real life currency (danish crownes)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('400x400')

ent = tk.Entry(root, fg="blue")
ent.pack()

def submit():
    ent.get()
    

sbmt = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", fg="blue", command=submit)
sbmt.pack()


if sbmt == "credits":
    print("hey")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the result when you do `ent.get()`. I think you should store that in a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here:
as Seth said:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('400x400')

ent = tk.Entry(root, fg="blue")
ent.pack()

def submit():
    something = ent.get()
    if  something == "credits":
        print("hey")


sbmt = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", fg="blue", command=submit)
sbmt.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

`sbmt` is not the same as `"credits"`. One is a `Button`, the other is a `str`. In fact, there is no possible way for the button to do or say anything relating to `"credits"`.

**Clarification:** Are you trying to see if `ent` says `"credits"` inside of it? If so, you need to save `ent.get()` to a variable.